# What is the correct syntax to for and SQL update in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I am trying to update an entry in the database using html and php. However, I keep getting an error saying my sql syntax is wrong.

Here is the code from the php file:

```
<?php 
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
//create connection
$dbconn = new mysqli($server, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

 $email_follow = $_POST['email_follow'];
 $follow = $_POST['follow'];

 $update = mysqli_query($dbconn, "UPDATE CustomerDetails SET Follow Up = '$follow' WHERE Email = '$email_follow'");

if ($dbconn->query($update) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $dbconn->error;
}
 ?>
```

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="cust_details_followup.php" method="post">       

Email:
<input type="email" name="email_follow" id="email_follow">

Enter Follow Up Details:
<input type="text" name="follow" id="follow">


<input type="submit" value="Update">

</form>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You table property `Follow Up` has a space,you need to add ` to wrap it

So change

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails SET Follow Up = '$follow' WHERE Email = '$email_follow'
```

to

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails SET `Follow Up` = '$follow' WHERE Email = '$email_follow'
```

Comment: do I use a back tick or just single quotes?

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as it is using single quotes, when you have to use backticks.

Comment: @zaveriraj2 updated my answer,you need to use backticks

Answer (score 0):

Need to use dot operator and need to use tick instead of single quote

> Tick - `Follow Up` - Correct.

```
$query = "UPDATE CustomerDetails
    SET `Follow Up` = '".$follow."'
    WHERE Email = '".$email_follow."'";

$update = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
```

Comment: Down voter don't forget to write comment when you down vote any ans.

Comment: it doesn't recognize the WHERE keyword when I try this.

Comment: `Follow Up` will still give an error. The answer that @lucumt provided is correct.

Comment: @dave are u sure lucumt query produce correct result ?

Comment: @zaveriraj2 you should define "doesn't recognize" or comment actual error i will easier for us to solve the issue.

Comment: You don't have to concat it with "the dot operator", it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below code

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails SET `Follow Up` = '".$follow."' WHERE Email = '".$email_follow."'
```